# Update Char(5) table HH:MM to add 12 for military time

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, set

We have a table that is char(5) and has data inserted like 6:45, 10:15, 3:00.  Our business hours are from 6-3pm...and this table doesn't have am/pm included -a as it is char(5).... I cannot change the table, I need to change the data daily after-the-upload.  All of the data loaded is x:xx or xx:xx format.

Yes, they 'should' convert before loading table, but they aren't.  How can I go in and 'fix' the entries... changing the 6:00,7:00,8:00,9:00,to have a 06,07,08,09 (leading zero) and change the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, beginning number to 13,14,15,16 with keeping the rest of the :xx part of the data?

Comment: This is why we need to use proper `datatype`. You should be using `TIME` datatype

Comment: @prdp . . . Although what you say is true, converting to a time would not produce a correct answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but it would make it easier to get the desired output at query time.

Comment: @Prdp ... yes, I agree with you... but, I didn't create the database, nor can I make changes to datatypes... I can only deal with what I have and suggest the vendor make these changes to their db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you never have data between 1AM and 5AM, and can safely assume those values need 12 hours added... then you can convert to a TIME type, evaluate the HOUR value, and add 12 only when its between 1 and 5 - and convert it all back to a char(5) to update.

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE (badTime CHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Sample(badTime)
VALUES ('6:45'),
       ('07:45'),
       ('8:45'),
       ('9:45'),
       ('10:45'),
       ('11:45'),
       ('12:45'),
       ('1:45'),
       ('2:45'),
       ('3:45'),
       (null),
       ('')

SELECT *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(TIME,badTime)) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN DATEADD(HH,12,CONVERT(TIME,badTime)) ELSE CONVERT(TIME,badTime) END,108)
-- UPDATE S SET badTime = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),CASE WHEN DATEPART(HH,CONVERT(TIME,badTime)) BETWEEN 1 AND 5 THEN DATEADD(HH,12,CONVERT(TIME,badTime)) ELSE CONVERT(TIME,badTime) END,108)
FROM @Sample S 
WHERE badTime IS NOT NULL AND badTime!=''
AND ISDATE(badTime)=1
```

Comment: This update works GREAT!!!  BUT.... one tiny thing.... for rows that have zero data the update is inserting 00:00 and then it looks like 12am on the GUI... how would I not inset data for NULL fields?

Comment: Add: `WHERE badTime IS NOT NULL AND badTime !=''` AND/OR `WHERE ISDATE(badTime)=1`

Answer (score 1):

One method is a `case`.  For the values you mention:

```
select (case when col like '[6789]:%' then stuff(col, 1, 1, '0' + left(col, 1)
             when col like '[12345]:%' then stuff(col, 1, 1, cast(left(col, 1) + 12 as char(2))
             else col
        end)
```

If you have some data that starts with a zero:

```
select (case when col like '[6789]:%' then stuff(col, 1, 1, '0' + left(col, 1)
             when col like '[12345]:%' then stuff(col, 1, 1, cast(left(col, 1) + 12 as char(2))
             when col like '0[12345]:%' then stuff(col, 1, 2, cast(left(col, 2) + 12 as char(2))
             else col
        end)
```

And, converting to a time data type uses similar logic:

```
select (case when hour(cast(col as time)) in (6, 7, 8, 9)
             then cast(col as time)
             when hour(cast(col as time) in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
             then dateadd(hour, 12, cast(col as time))
             else cast(col as time)
        end)
```

Comment: These statements won't update ...but change the output... I need to change the data in the table to xx:xx ...   I tried to replace example #1 to see output...but I get an error when putting my table/column in. :(  `
select (CASE WHEN rt.stop_time like '[6789]:%' THEN STUFF (rt.stop_time, 1, 1, '0' + left(rt.stop_time, 1)
             WHEN rt.stop_time like '[12345]:%' THEN STUFF(rt.stop_time, 1, 1, cast(left(rt.stop_time, 1) + 12 as char(2))
             ELSE rt.stop_time
        END)
from passport_travel rt
where RT.ID = 1118874454`

Comment: @KAT . . . A `select` is easily changed to an update.  Your original question was not clear that you want to modify the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...true that....I will be more clear next time... I appreciate all of the help!  The SQL is one of my many hats @ work and I am still learning.... thanks so much :)